# Adding Icons to Tabs in TableLayout Using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I am having trouble in adapter line no 3 after updating android studio version. The same code worked for previous version, but now it is giving an error in the adapter.

```
val fragmentAdapter=  MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
            val tabs = findViewById<View>(R.id.tab_layout) as TabLayout
            viewpager_main.adapter(fragmentAdapter)
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager_main)
            tabs.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_library_books)
            tabs.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dashboard)
            tabs.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_person)
```

Comment: Did you try `viewpager_main.adapter = fragmentAdapter` ?

Comment: Post your log error

Comment: yes i tried but not working

Comment: Unresolved reference: swing 
Type mismatch: inferred type is TabLayout! but Int was expected

Comment: 07-10 21:52:10.373 4448-4448/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system